# concat ' in JS Code (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi together I've got a problem with the ' and " in my js code.

```
   $(".searchResultsMember table").append("<tr>" +
              "<td>" +
              "<a href='#' title='Statistik' data-container='body' 
data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' onclick='open_statistic('/memberships/statistik/', '"+ 
data.results[i].firstname +" "+ 
data.results[i].lastname +"','"+ data.results[i].id +
"');return false; '><img src='/images/iconpack/table.png' alt='Statistic'/></a> "+
     [....]
```

The Problem is in the onclick part .. can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Why not assign the listener separately ?

Comment: I can do that yep ... but I want to know how to boxing the ' " :) just to know it

Comment: Why not just moving the troublesome part to a separate variable? I mean this one
``open_statistic('/memberships/statistik/', '"+ data.results[i].firstname +" "+ data.results[i].lastname +"','"+ data.results[i].id +"');return false; ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can mix and match `'` and `"` as long as you use them in pairs, eg:

```
var x = "a";
var y = 'b';
```

You can also combine these on the same line, eg:

```
var z = "a" + 'b';
```

so you pick the one you need depending on the content (unless you have some nefarious coding standards written by someone that doesn't understand this (which I've seen..))

to concat a single quote, surround in doubles and the other way, eg:

```
var x = "'" + '"';   x == '"
```

this also applies to attributes:

```
<a href="#" title='double quote (")'>
<a href="#" title="single quote (')">
```

so you can fix your code by changing the quotes:

```
$(".searchResultsMember table").append(
          "<tr>"
          + "<td>"
          + "<a href='#' title='Statistik'" 
          + " data-container='body' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'"
          + ' onclick="open_statistic('  
          + "'/memberships/statistik/', '"
          + data.results[i].firstname 
          + " " 
          + data.results[i].lastname 
          + "','" 
          + data.results[i].id 
          + "');return false; "
          + '">'
          + "<img src='/images/iconpack/table.png' alt='Statistic'/></a> "+
[....]
```

---

But, having done this for you above - it's really confusing!  (and therefore prone to errors)

So break it up into steps with variables, and break out just the double quotes, eg:

```
var onclick = "open_statistic('/memberships/statistik/', '" + ... + "');return false;";

$(".searchResultsMember table").append(
          "<tr>"
          + "<td>"
          + "<a href='#' title='Statistik'" 
          + " data-container='body' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom'"
          + " onclick=" + '"' + onclick + '"' + ">" 
          ....
```